# References on infinite series with continued fraction partial convergents

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, continued-fractions

Define the following partial convergents in terms of simple continued fractions:

$$a_{0} = \frac{1}{1}, \quad a_{1} = \frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{1}}, \quad a_{2} = \frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{{1+\frac{1}{1}}}}, \ \dots $$

Then [the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Continued_fraction_and_square_root) of these partial convergents goes to the inverse of the golden ratio: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} =  \phi^{-1} = \phi -1.$$

I wonder whether convergent infinite series involving such partial convergents have been studied and evaluated. Consider, for instance, the following series:

\begin{align*} 
S_{1} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( a_{n} - \phi^{-1} \right), \text{ and} \\
S_{2} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{k}}{2^{k}} \ . 
\end{align*}

> **Question**: has the closed form evaluation of infinite series involving continued fraction partial convergents, like $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$, been studied and described in the literature before?